# C++ priority queue does not respect FIFO order

Tags: c++, priority-queue, fifo

I'm using the STL priority_queue to collect objects of my own class Lettura.

```
//---------LETTURA----------

enum Priority {zero, standard, urgent};

class Lettura{
public:
int valore;
char sensore;
Priority priorita;

Lettura():  valore(0),sensore('\0'),priorita(zero){}
Lettura(const int val, const char s='\0', const Priority p=zero):  valore(val),sensore(s), priorita(p){}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Lettura & lett);
};
```

I want them to be popped in order of decrescent "priorita", but I also want same-priority elements to be popped with FIFO policy like in a normal queue.
I get same-priority elements in a random order:

```
top: l5  urgent
top: l1  standard
top: l4  standard
top: l6  standard
top: l2  standard
top: l3  standard
```

I would like same-priority elements in a FIFO order:

```
top: l5  urgent
top: l1  standard
top: l2  standard
top: l3  standard
top: l4  standard
top: l6  standard
```

This is my code:

```
int main() {
std::priority_queue<Lettura, std::vector<Lettura>, std::less<Lettura> > coda;

Lettura l1(50,'a',standard);
Lettura l2(50,'b',standard);
Lettura l3(120,'c',standard);
Lettura l4(100,'d',standard);
Lettura l5(30,'e',urgent);
Lettura l6(35,'f',standard);

coda.push(l1);
coda.push(l2);
coda.push(l3);
coda.push(l4);
coda.push(l5);
coda.push(l6);


cout<<"top: "<<coda.top()<<"\n";    coda.pop();
cout<<"top: "<<coda.top()<<"\n";    coda.pop();
cout<<"top: "<<coda.top()<<"\n";    coda.pop();
cout<<"top: "<<coda.top()<<"\n";    coda.pop();
cout<<"top: "<<coda.top()<<"\n";    coda.pop();
cout<<"top: "<<coda.top()<<"\n";    coda.pop();
}
```

I have implemented these comparison methods:

```
bool operator<(const Lettura& l1, const Lettura& l2){
return l1.priorita < l2.priorita;
}

bool operator<=(const Lettura& l1, const Lettura& l2){
return l1.priorita <= l2.priorita;
}
```

I have also tried with different queue constructors but unsuccessfully:

```
std::priority_queue<Lettura> coda;
std::priority_queue<Lettura, std::vector<Lettura>, std::less_equal<Lettura> > coda;
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You are showing values 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 but pushing values 50, 50, 100 and so on. What values are you using?

Comment: Those are not 11, 12... but l1,l2,l3... with 'L' not '1'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code appears to be working, in that you get the urgent items out first. There is no sub-ordering by insertion time in a heap based priority queue, so you will get the items with the same priority out in an undefined order, except that they will be after items with a higher priority. You need to add an extra field, such as time put into queue, and use that along with your Priority enum in your comparison operator.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another possible stable_priority_queue implementation that keeps the same interface provided by priority_queue:

```
template <class T>
struct stable_element
{
    stable_element(T&& o, std::size_t c)
        : object_(std::move(o))
        , insertion_order_(c)
    {
    }
    stable_element(const T& o, std::size_t c)
        : object_(o)
        , insertion_order_(c)
    {
    }
    operator T() { return object_; }

    T object_;
    std::size_t insertion_order_;
};

template <class T>
bool operator<(const stable_element<T>& lhs, const stable_element<T>& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.object_ < rhs.object_) || (!(rhs.object_ < lhs.object_) && (rhs.insertion_order_ < lhs.insertion_order_));
}

template <class T,
          class Container = std::vector<stable_element<T>>,
          class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>>
class stable_priority_queue : public std::priority_queue<stable_element<T>, Container, Compare>
{
    using stableT = stable_element<T>;
    using std::priority_queue<stableT, Container, Compare>::priority_queue;
public:
    const T& top() { return this->c.front().object_; }
    void push(const T& value) {
        this->c.push_back(stableT(value, counter_++));
        std::push_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
    }
    void push(T&& value) {
        this->c.push_back(stableT(std::move(value), counter_++));
        std::push_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
    }
    template<class ... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args) {
        this->c.emplace_back(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), counter_++);
        std::push_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
    }
    void pop() {
        std::pop_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
        this->c.pop_back();
        if (this->empty()) counter_ = 0;
    }

protected:
    std::size_t counter_ = 0;
};
```

In a std::priority_queue, there are protected members `c` and `comp` that correspond respectively to the underlying container and the comparison function object. With this approach of inheriting from std::priority_queue, we need to modify the behavior of `top`, `push`, `emplace` and `pop`. The documentation for [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) for each of these function provides the implementation of those functions in terms of what it does with the `c` and `comp` members. This was quite helpful in rewriting the modified member functions in terms of `stable_element<T>`.

To use this stable_priority_queue for the OPs use case, we just need to provide a `bool operator<(const Lettura& l, const Lettura& r) { return l.priorita < r.priorita; }` to sort the priority as desired:

```
enum Priority
{
    zero, standard, urgent
};

inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Priority& p)
{
    switch (p) {
        case zero:
            os << "zero"; break;
        case standard:
            os << "standard"; break;
        case urgent:
            os << "urgent"; break;
    }
    return os;
}

class Lettura
{
public:
    int      valore;
    char     sensore;
    Priority priorita;

    Lettura()
        : valore(0)
        , sensore('\0')
        , priorita(zero) {}

    Lettura(const int val, const char s = '\0', const Priority p = zero)
        : valore(val)
        , sensore(s)
        , priorita(p) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Lettura& lett)
    {
        return out << "{ valore: " << lett.valore << ", sensore: " << lett.sensore << ", priorita: " << lett.priorita
                   << " }";
    }
};

bool operator<(const Lettura& l, const Lettura& r)
{
    return l.priorita < r.priorita;
}

int main()
{
    stable_priority_queue<Lettura> coda;

    Lettura l1(50, 'a', standard);
    Lettura l2(50, 'b', standard);
    Lettura l3(120, 'c', standard);
    Lettura l5(30, 'e', urgent);
    Lettura l6(35, 'f', standard);

    coda.push(l1);
    coda.push(l2);
    coda.push(l3);
    coda.emplace(100, 'd', standard);
    coda.emplace(l5);
    coda.emplace(l6);

    while (!coda.empty()) {
        std::cout << "top: " << coda.top() << "\n";
        coda.pop();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
top: { valore: 30, sensore: e, priorita: urgent }
top: { valore: 50, sensore: a, priorita: standard }
top: { valore: 50, sensore: b, priorita: standard }
top: { valore: 120, sensore: c, priorita: standard }
top: { valore: 100, sensore: d, priorita: standard }
top: { valore: 35, sensore: f, priorita: standard }
```

Here is a [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Qnhd72U2udxkCtUO) demonstration of all of this put together

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Comment: @ConfusedByCode I expanded my answer. Hopefully this is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple implementation of a stable priority queue.

It attempts to resist ordering exhaustion by zeroing the insertion counter whenever the queue is empty:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>


enum Priority
{
    zero, standard, urgent
};

inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Priority& p)
{
    switch (p) {
        case zero:
            return os << "zero";
        case standard:
            return os << "standard";
        case urgent:
            return os << "urgent";
    }
}

class Lettura
{
public:
    int      valore;
    char     sensore;
    Priority priorita;

    Lettura()
        : valore(0)
        , sensore('\0')
        , priorita(zero) {}

    Lettura(const int val, const char s = '\0', const Priority p = zero)
        : valore(val)
        , sensore(s)
        , priorita(p) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Lettura& lett)
    {
        return out << "{ valore: " << lett.valore << ", sensore: " << lett.sensore << ", priorita: " << lett.priorita
                   << " }";
    }
};


template<class T, class Comp>
struct stable_priority_queue
{
    using counter_type = std::size_t;

    struct Proxy
    {
        Proxy(T&& o, counter_type c)
            : object(std::move(o))
            , insertion_order_(c) {}

        Proxy(const T& o, counter_type c)
            : object(o)
            , insertion_order_(c) {}

        T            object;
        counter_type insertion_order_;
    };

    struct ProxyComp
    {
        bool operator ()(Proxy const& l, Proxy const& r) const
        {
            if (major_order_(l.object, r.object))
                return true;
            if (major_order_(r.object, l.object))
                return false;
            return minor_order_(l.insertion_order_, r.insertion_order_);
        }

        Comp           major_order_;
        std::greater<> minor_order_;
    };


    decltype(auto) push(T item)
    {
        return queue_.emplace(std::move(item), counter_++);
    }

    T const& top() const
    {
        return queue_.top().object;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        queue_.pop();
        if (queue_.empty())
            counter_ = 0;
    }

    std::priority_queue<Proxy, std::vector<Proxy>, ProxyComp> queue_;
    counter_type                                              counter_ = 0;
};

struct lower_priority
{
    bool operator ()(const Lettura& l, const Lettura& r) const
    {
        return l.priorita < r.priorita;
    }
};

int main()
{
    stable_priority_queue<Lettura, lower_priority> coda;

    Lettura l1(50, 'a', standard);
    Lettura l2(50, 'b', standard);
    Lettura l3(120, 'c', standard);
    Lettura l4(100, 'd', standard);
    Lettura l5(30, 'e', urgent);
    Lettura l6(35, 'f', standard);

    coda.push(l1);
    coda.push(l2);
    coda.push(l3);
    coda.push(l4);
    coda.push(l5);
    coda.push(l6);


    std::cout << "top: " << coda.top() << "\n";
    coda.pop();
    std::cout << "top: " << coda.top() << "\n";
    coda.pop();
    std::cout << "top: " << coda.top() << "\n";
    coda.pop();
    std::cout << "top: " << coda.top() << "\n";
    coda.pop();
    std::cout << "top: " << coda.top() << "\n";
    coda.pop();
    std::cout << "top: " << coda.top() << "\n";
    coda.pop();
}
```

expected results:

```
top: { valore: 30, sensore: e, priorita: urgent }
top: { valore: 50, sensore: a, priorita: standard }
top: { valore: 50, sensore: b, priorita: standard }
top: { valore: 120, sensore: c, priorita: standard }
top: { valore: 100, sensore: d, priorita: standard }
top: { valore: 35, sensore: f, priorita: standard }
```

Answer (score -4):

It seems it is a bug of the compiler library and of the C++ Standard. They break the algorithm of selecting of the maximum element in the priority_queue. See the thread opened by me according to heaps.

[Why does std::is_heap use random access iterators instead of forward iterators?](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/MRzOkmQT0lA)

A'm going to prepare the corresponding proposal.

Comment: It's not obvious from that link that it  is a compiler bug or a Standard bug - it's just your opinion of  how it ought to work, which I don't want to get into here. In either case, it doesn't help the OP.

Comment: @latedeveloper It means only one thing you do not know the algorithms with heaps. They are described in many books on algorithms. Please read them before to say something about the algorithms In the books there are described how elements shall be selected.